# Why is my mmv command not overwriting the files?

Tags: command-line, mmv

I have a batch file that, among other things, uses the command `mmv` to rename some files. The relevant line is like this:

```
mmv "$BASEDIR/files/*.txt" "$BASEDIR/files/#1.strings"
```

In essence it works, but the problem is that it keeps asking me for confirmation to overwrite files when they happen to already exist. I want it to just go ahead and do that without confirmation, so I checked the [man page for `mmv`](http://ss64.com/bash/mmv.html), and it says to simply use the `-o` option, like this:

```
mmv -o "$BASEDIR/files/*.txt" "$BASEDIR/files/#1.strings"
```

It's not making any difference, though. Every time I run my script, when it comes to the `mmv` part, it starts asking me confirmation.

Why is the `-o` option not doing its job, and how do I get `mmv` to overwrite without asking confirmation?

Answer (score 8):

Try adding -d to your command line:

> Collisions and Deletions
>
> When any two or more matching files would have to be moved, copied, or
>   linked to the same target filename, mmv detects the condition as an
>   error before performing any actions. Furthermore, mmv checks if any of
>   its actions will result in the destruction of existing files.
>
> If the -d (delete) option is specified, all file deletions or
>   overwrites are done silently.

Comment: Thanks for this. Adding the `-d` option now prevents confirmation. However, one additional issue. It's not moving the files to the new names, it's copying them. So, in the directory I'm acting on, I end up with two sets of the files, one with the old names and one with the new. The man page seems to indicate `mmv -xo -d` or `mmv -mo -d` should move and delete the original copies, but I just get it outputting a usage error. How do I get it to remove the files with the old name?